# URL doesn't expire after set time

Tags: php, time, date-comparison

So I have a URL that should turn invalid after an hour. For some reason it never turns invalid. Here's the code,

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once '../db.php';

//DB query
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT token_created_at from reset WHERE token = :urltoken");
$stmt->bindValue(':urltoken', $_GET['token']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     $token_created_at = $row['token_created_at'];
}

$_SESSION['token'] = $_GET['token'];

//Remove after testing
 echo $token_created_at."<br>";

$my_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $token_created_at);

//Modify error
$expires_at = $my_dt->modify('+1 hour');

//Return current time to match
echo $current_time = date('m-d-Y H:i:s', time());


?>
<?php if($current_time < $expires_at) : ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="a.php">
            <input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password">
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Password, again">
            <br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php else : ?>
<h1>Link expired</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas? In the DB, `token` is stored as `06-27-2014 09:10:50` and current time is `06-28-2014 09:15:27`, so it should be expired. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you're using MySQL, I would recommend storing date/time types as `DATETIME` columns; at the very least it would standardise the format to "Y-m-d H:i:s".

Comment: Also, why are you using the token value as the primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a DateTime object against a string. You can't do that. Either compare both as strings or DateTime objects. I recommend that latter.

```
$current_time = new DateTime();
<?php if($current_time < $expires_at) : ?>
```

You also don't need to capture the result of `$my_dt->modify('+1 hour');` as it modifies `$my_dt` in place. So you can do:

```
$my_dt->modify('+1 hour');
$current_time = new DateTime();
<?php if($current_time < $expires_at) : ?>
```